# Laravel 4 : Best Practice to Trim Input before Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Now, I do trim for each input separately like below code:

```
$username = trim(Input::get('username'));
$password = trim(Input::get('password'));
$email    = trim(Input::get('email'));

$validator = Validator::make(array('username' => $username, 
                                   'password' => $password, 
                                   'email'    => $email), 
                             array('username' => 'required|min:6', 
                                   'password' => 'required|min:6', 
                                   'email'    => 'email'));
```

Is any approach to do Trim at the same time with

`Input::all()` or `Input::only('username', 'password', 'email')`?

And what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: You could do it like this: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1909

Comment: It means that I need to do `new User` before validation? Now I use `User::create()` after validation.

Comment: You want to trim spaces from passwords? o wauw.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

***Note:*** This solution won't work if any of your inputs are arrays (such as "data[]").

You may try this, trim using this one line of code before validation:

```
Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
```

Now do the rest of your coding

```
$username = Input::get('username'); // it's trimed 
// ...
Validator::make(...);
```

If you want to exclude some inputs from trimming then you may use following instead if `all()`

```
Input::except('password');
```

Or you may use

```
Input::only(array('username'));
```

**Update**: Since `Laravel 5.4.*` inputs are trimmed because of new `TrimStrings`middleware. So, no need to worry about it because this middleware executes on every request and it handles array inputs as well.

Comment: what `input::merge()` exactly do? I can't find it in official document. http://laravel.com/docs/requests

Comment: It merges new inputs with old inputs.

Comment: But here, it's replacing the inputs with trimed input because arra_map returns another array of trimed inputs.

Comment: Nice Answer. Add one line and just like trim it at the front end! Thanks~

Comment: Doesn't work when using array parameters like `<input name="data[]">`

Comment: For maximum efficiency, just add this as a filter in your route so you won't have to keep _trimming_ manually. Also, Dustin Graham, it won't really work since it's an array. You'll have to scan each element manually which can be easily done.

Comment: When tried as above it returns error - trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @user269867 This solution doesn't work if any of your inputs are arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your project, the below might be too intrusive/generalized/etc for your needs; customize as needed.

- I'm making use of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#112857) little recursive array map function in order to process arrays of inputs without error.
- Any field named `password` (and its confirmation) is excluded since people might want to use space as part of further obscuring their passwords.
- Space has special meaning in some types of text. For example in Markdown, [two or more spaces at the end of a line inserts `<br>`](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p). Though you probably won't need this at the start or at the end of the blob. YMMV.

**`app/helpers.php`**

```
/**
 * @param callable $callback
 * @param array    $array
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#112857
 */
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = array_map_recursive($callback, $array[$key]);
        } else {
            $array[$key] = call_user_func($callback, $array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

**`app/filters.php`**

```
App::before(
    function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        // Trim all input
        $request->merge(
            array_map_recursive(
                "trim",
                array_except(
                    $request->all(),
                    ["password", "password_confirmation"]
                )
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: You can also avoid using functions (no object/class around it) by using an utilities class (re-run `composer dump-autoload` !). E.g. place them in `app\libraries\Arrays.php` assuming that `Arrays.php` contains an utilities class for array operations. Just a bit more OOP. :-)

Comment: And maybe consider adding type-hints. Or is Laravel 4 not running on PHP 5 and higher?

Comment: @Roland in case that was directed at me: To be honest, I haven't been working on Laravel (or PHP) for years. So; sorry, no idea about the current status :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the array_map function of php, to trim the content of your input array.

```
$validator = Validator::make(array_map('trim',Input::all()),
                             array('username' => 'required|min:6', 
                                   'password' => 'required|min:6', 
                                   'email'    => 'email'));
```

Or if you want a variable you can use later:

```
$inputs = array_map('trim', Input::only('username', 'password', 'email'))
```

Comment: Nice, but I think it's better to assign a variable that can be later reused with `User::create()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$attributes = Input::only('username', 'password', 'email');

foreach ($attributes as &$value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    //and any further preprocessing you want
}

$validator = Validator::make($attributes, array(
    'username' => 'required|min:6', 
    'password' => 'required|min:6', 
    'email'    => 'email'
));

//now you may pass preprocessed $attributes to the model create() method,
//still having the original input untouched if you may need it
```

Usually, I also use this approach to replace optional values with `null` when they're empty, because I prefer to store them in DB as `NULL` rather than empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a better practice to do trimming in the model instead of in controllers because then you don't have to duplicate code in all your controllers to trim the same things over and over:

```
public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
{
  $this->attributes['username'] = trim($value);
}
```

This way, you never have to remember to trim anything model attributes in your controllers. The model will take care of it and you don't have to worry about it ever again.

As far as trimming everything at once vs. individually, I think the difference is so small that no human would ever notice the difference.

Comment: you want to factor this into the model, but why would you give the model a responsibility of the controller? i mean, in the OP case, his controller is responsible for sanitizing the input data.

Comment: @Alexandre Martini The controller should only be responsible for taking requests and returning responses.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the above is best. Generally you'll want to filter on all input apart from password and password_confirmation fields. Also doing it with a single line in a filter is nice.

// app/filters.php

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Trim all input
    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::except(['password', 'password_confirmation'])));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

an improvement in [Halil Özgür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372654/halil-%C3%96zg%C3%BCr) code to remove all spaces, `<br>`, `<br >`, `<br class="asdasd">`, `&nbsp`, etc

```
// filters.php
App::before(function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $request->merge(
        array_map_recursive(
            "preg_replace",
            array_except(
                $request->all(),
                ["password", "password_confirmation"]
            )
        )
    );
});

// helpers.php
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = array_map_recursive($callback, $array[$key]);
        } else {
            $array[$key] = call_user_func_array($callback, ['#(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}$#i', '', $array[$key]]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` Middleware.

You do not need to do anything extra, because those middlewares are built-in to Laravel 5.4.[See this Post](https://blog.maqe.com/dealing-with-spaces-in-form-inputs-using-middleware-in-laravel-5-4-ffb37cd019e6)

Edit:
[What if I am not using Laravel 5.4?](https://blog.maqe.com/dealing-with-spaces-in-form-inputs-using-middleware-in-laravel-5-4-ffb37cd019e6)

- Let’s copy the code from Laravel’s Github. you can get from [here](https://gist.github.com/damjangkae/90c7da95aec72d2d01b3be1e0a00edfa)
- Then make sure that Laravel knows your middlewares in Kernel.php.

  protected $middleware = [
      // previous middleware
      \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
  ];

Comment: The questioner has Laravel 4.x, not 5.4. But yes, since 5.4, this is possible. So no down and up vote from me. So with 5.3 (large project) I have to stick with the filter version?

Comment: In Laravel 4, You can copy [TrimStrings](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php) to your middleware directory. and use in your route.

Comment: Yes, you *can* but **should** not mix classes from different version. ;-) Maybe it "works" but it is generally not a good idea because the said reason.