# Laravel 4: How to trim every Input::all() data?

Tags: php, laravel-4, trim

My usual way of trimming user input in a laravel controller is like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (isset($_POST)) $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
    if (isset($_GET)) $_GET = array_map('trim', $_GET);
}
```

How do I trim an `Input` class in laravel in a similar way?

-- SOLVED --

Nevermind, I find `Input::merge()` already

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 : Best Practice to Trim Input before Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399326/laravel-4-best-practice-to-trim-input-before-validation)

Answer (score 5):

add this line to trim all input:

```
Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
```