# unusual error occur in laravel validation

Tags: validation, laravel

In my laravel 4 project i gave a validation like this

```
'contact_no' => 'numeric|digits_between:10,10',
```

But this shows error in a weird situation. If I copy and paste the phone number in the field it shows validation error `"The contact no must be a number."` But when I type the phone number everything is fine.

Did anyone knows why laravel shows this kind of error? and how I can resolve this? 
**The screen shot is:**

[image]

Comment: I think its due to space issue between the string.PLease check that

Comment: no.. i checked the field in that no space before or after or in between  the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy a string from a source which is not plain text (but formated text) sometimes there are invisible spaces copied along with the string. I had this strange behavior several times.

#### How you test it

- Open notepad (or any plain text editor)
- Type your number
- Copy it from there
- Paste it in your form

I guess this number will work.

#### How you could try to go around this problem

Before validation `trim` the input data from `contact_no` to remove all whitespaces first. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: should i give it like this `Validator::make(array_map('trim',Input::all()), $rules,$messages);`  ??

Comment: this would trim all of your input fields I guess. I would try to only trim the `contact_no` field, because if you have other input fields (lets say with text) their whitespaces would be removed too. Here is an example in the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399326/laravel-4-best-practice-to-trim-input-before-validation

Comment: ok i gave this before my validation `Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::only('contact_no')));` and then `Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules,$messages)`. is this correct??