# Trim inputs before validation in the Requests - Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am using **laravel 5.1** and I am validating the inputs in a Requests as below,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2'
    ];
}
```

**Here if the first_name = '    s' validation passes which i not expected, I need to trim the inputs before the validation happens.**

I tried like this,

```
public function rules()
{
    $this->replace(array_map('trim', $this->all()));

    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2'
    ];
}
```

But I am getting the same result.

I saw something related to **laravel 4.x** ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399326/laravel-4-best-practice-to-trim-input-before-validation))

How to get this done?

**NOTE:** I am **not validating in the controller** by creating a validation instance, I am **using  Request to validate the request**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Validation Trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386203/laravel-5-validation-trim)

Comment: @arogachev **NO** its not using **Request** class to validate the request. that one and the link which i provided in the question is same.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope this might help you.

```
public function rules()
{
    $input = $this->all();
    $input['first_name'] = trim($input['first_name']);
    $this->replace($input);

    return [
        'first_name'    => 'required|min:2',
    ];
}
```